# "As per" and "in the case being"?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, word-usage

Take the following text into account:

> These airstrikes would not only be punishment for Assad's use of
>   chemical weapons against civilians amid the three-year-long Syrian
>   Uprising (**according to** the Obama administration), but would also serve
>   another purpose - to protect U.S. personnel **in the case being** where
>   the ISIS, otherwise known as the Islamic State, were to be involved.

I was wondering, does the phrase "in the case being" make sense here in the context it is being used in? If not, what would be a better alternative?

Also, is the phrase "as per" more professional than simply using "according to"? If that's the case, would I use:

(as per the Obama administration)...

or

(per the Obama administration)...

**EDIT:**

I think instead of "in the case being," "in the case" would be good enough. However, I would still appreciate some feedback on this. Also, would "in the case being" make sense?

Answer (score 1):

"In the case being" simply does not make sense, here or elsewhere. *In the case* would be acceptable though imperfect in your example; the verb would have to be *were involved* rather than *were to be*. I think the journalist is just too much of a hurry to think of the best construction, "if ISIS were to become involved".

And *as per* is a horrible construction. It originated where "according to" was too long, and reports have been known to include 'numbers as per margin', instead of 'as set out in the margin.' It's not incomprehensible, but will never be regarded as "professional".